# Wants SQL Server CONSTRAINT to NOT allow a certain SPECIFIC string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a practice Database using SQL Server 2017 and SMMS, it is for a record store, I am creating table ARTISTS, and I want a CONSTRAINT to NOT allow Modest Mouse or Good Charlotte in the ARTIST field. We don't sell those. Anyway,

```
CREATE TABLE ARTIST (
  ArtistID       Int     NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  ArtistName     Char(30)               NOT NULL,
  Genre          Char(15)               NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT     ArtistPK               PRIMARY KEY(ArtistID),
  CONSTRAINT     CheckCertainArtists    CHECK ([ArtistName] NOT 'Modest Mouse' OR 'Good Charlotte')
);
```

Needless to say this did not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts... this question should be tagged [ sql-server ] and not tagged [ mysql ] (its pretty clear that this question pertains to Microsoft SQL Server, and not MySQL. These are two significantly *different* relational database management systems.

Comment: You may wish to revisit your datatypes. `char` is a good choice where all values are going to be the exact length you've specified. `varchar` (or `nvarchar`) is a far better choice when the values have various different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Your description suggests a simple `CHECK` constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_artist_artistname
    CHECK (ArtistName NOT IN ('Modest Mouse' , 'Good Charlotte'));
```

However, I find this a curious restriction.  There are a zillion other names, many of which may be artists that you don't sell (or not even artists at all).  It is unclear why you are stopping at these two.  Perhaps you want to include only artists that you do sell.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
CONSTRAINT CheckCertainArtists CHECK (
  ArtistName <> 'Modest Mouse' AND ArtistName <> 'Good Charlotte'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CHECK** constraint like this:

```
CONSTRAINT chkArtistArtistname
CHECK (ArtistName NOT IN ('Modest Mouse' , 'Good Charlotte'));
```